# How do I re-configure grub options

Tags: grub

I've searched this topic and I can't find an article with a plausible solution, to my problem.

I installed Windows 7 first, with 100gb of disk space.

I then created the necessary partitions via Windows.

Finally I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on the remaining 400GB of disk space.

During the Ubuntu installation I installed the Ubuntu bootloader on `/dev/sda3` which Windows (as expected never granted me the option pre-boot for which OS I wanted to boot). So I re-installed Ubuntu on that `/dev/sda3` partition, overriding the Windows 7 bootloader.

Now when I boot windows 7, it runs **GNU Grub**, so like an infinite loop.

How can I reconfigure grub to say:

/dev/sda is the bootloader.
/dev/sda2 is Windows.
/dev/sda3 is Ubuntu.

Re-installing windows and my partitions isn't an option, purchasing software for windows isn't an option (there's a reason I use linux - it's not because it's free, but because you don't have to install many programs to get stuff working; and overall it's a robust OS).

Comment: Which grub version you have?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the latest ubuntu offers GRUB2.

Configuration changes are normally made to the /etc/default/grub file and to the custom scripts located in /etc/grub.d. No changes are made to the GRUB 2 menu until the update-grub command is run as root. This command runs the GRUB 2 configuration scripts and updates the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file.